# SQL Server trigger for an inserted and/or updated record, based on value of a field

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have what I think is a very simple requirement but because I'm new, I can't quite get it working correctly.

I have a table full of customer data with an pk of `cust_no`. When a new customer row is inserted, and the email address field is not null, I'd like to set a date field in the same row to `getdate()`.

I'd also like to do the same thing if the customer record is updated with a new email address, but again, only if the email address field is not null, and was actually updated with a new email address.

The purpose of this is to run a report of new email addresses collected during a specific time frame.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important point to remember that a lot of folks get wrong: triggers in SQL Server are called **once per statement** - not once per row.

So if you happen to have a `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement that inserts or updates 50 rows at once - your trigger will be called **once**, and the pseudo tables (`Inserted` and `Deleted` in the UPDATE case) will contain 50 rows. You need to take that into account when writing your triggers.

The INSERT case is simpler - so here it goes:

```
-- CREATE after INSERT trigger
CREATE TRIGGER trgCustomerInsert
ON dbo.Customer AFTER INSERT
AS
    -- update your "Customer" table
    UPDATE dbo.Customer
    SET SomeDateColumn = GETDATE()  -- set date column to GETDATE()
    FROM dbo.Customer c
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON c.cust_no = i.cust_no  -- on all those rows inserted
    WHERE c.Email IS NOT NULL   -- where the e-mail address is NOT NULL
```

You basically just join the `Inserted` pseudo table (that contains all the rows just inserted - with all their column values) against the "real" customer table, and you update all customer rows that were just inserted, and where the e-mail column is NOT NULL.

The update is a bit trickier - since you want to update only those rows where the e-mail column was NULL before, and is NOT NULL now, after the update. So you need to join to the `Deleted` pseudo table, which contains the "old" values (before the UPDATE).

All those rows that have been updated, and where the old value for the e-mail in `Deleted` was NULL, and the current value in the Customer table is NOT NULL - those are the ones you want to update the date column for.

```
-- CREATE after UPDATE trigger
CREATE TRIGGER trgCustomerUpdate
ON dbo.Customer AFTER UPDATE
AS
    -- update your "Customer" table
    UPDATE dbo.Customer
    SET SomeDateColumn = GETDATE()  -- set date column to GETDATE()
    FROM dbo.Customer c
    INNER JOIN Deleted d ON c.cust_no = d.cust_no   
    WHERE 
       -- where new value of e-mail is NOT NULL
       -- and the old value (in "Deleted") was in fact NULL
       c.Email IS NOT NULL AND d.EMail IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I am learning a lot from your reply. I'm implementing it now, will let you know how it goes. Thank you for pointing out the fact that the whole batch is updated, not just a row. That was something I had overlooked in my narrow approach to this.

Comment: @user2100137: glad to be of help!